# Get LinkedHashMap index of a key

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

How can I get the index of a key in LinkedHashMap ?

for example I got this :

```
index          key          value
0              "a"           10
1              "b"           20
2              "c"           30
```

Now I want to get the index of the key "b". What is in this case 1.

Any ways without a runtime of O(n) ? 
And I will use it in a loop so for example `new ArrayList<String>(mapIndex.keySet()).indexOf(position_with_section_map[position]);`
wouldn't be a solution for me

Comment: Use it in a loop how? There's no API for using it at all, let alone in a loop. And the index values you've shown are only correct if the entries were inserted in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Louis Wasserman answer instead of creating a new map,you can move the index and value to a Pojo and save that as the value in the Map.

```
class Test{
int index;
int value;
public int getIndex();
public int getValue();
}
```

Use the LinkedHashMap as LinkedHashMap String,Test>

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this without a runtime of O(n) just from a `LinkedHashMap`.  You could keep an extra `Map<String, Integer>` to keep the indices of the elements yourself, but that's really the only thing you can do.